# api doc for bitcoin gold on testnet

Tags: bitcoin-gold

I'm looking for an api doc for bitcoin gold on testnet to create, receive and list transactions and accounts. so far I've found this https://bitcoingold.org/testnet-v3/. I'd be thankful if someone shed some light

Comment: The rpc should be identical to the regular Bitcoind, so any library or tools that interface with that should work

Answer (score 1):

The project Wiki on GitHub probably has the info you're looking for:

Technical Spec: https://github.com/BTCGPU/BTCGPU/wiki/Technical-Spec
Testnet v3: https://github.com/BTCGPU/BTCGPU/wiki/Testnet-v3